# JSP function return some strange value

Tags: function, jsp, parameters

I have a problem in below function. I don't understand why the parameter "data" will return "1", "2" and"3".Please help to explain.Thanks.

```
function submitRegistrationForm() {
    var queryString = $('#registerForm').formSerialize();
    $.post('../member/registration.do?method=register&key=<%=RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(64) %>', queryString, function(data) {
        if (data != ''&& data !='1'&& data !='2'&& data !='3'){
            var arr = data.split('-');
            var urlstr = '../member/registration.do?method=regisration&key=<%=RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(64) %>&altId='+trim(arr[0])+'&vipKo='+arr[1];
            parent.window.location.href = urlstr;
            parent.$.fancybox.close(); 

        }else if(data == "1"){

          $('#errorMessage2').html("INVALID MEMBER NO.");

        }else if(data == "2"){

          $('#errorMessage2').html("THE MEMBER NO. HAS VOIDED");

        }
        else if(data == "3"){

          $('#errorMessage2').html("THIS MEMBER NO. HAS ALREADY REGISTERED");

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a JAVASCRIPT function, not JSP.  It may be in a JSP page, but its Javascript. `$.post(` is a jQuery shortcut for using Ajax to send a POST.  Its using Ajax to call a Servlet mapped to `../member/registration.do`.   The variable `data` is whatever is printed to the response object in that Servlet when its called by the Ajax.  So apparently `registration.do` is supposed to be printing 1, 2, or 3, with no whitespace.  If you are having a problem where it is not returning 1, 2, or 3, it may be because you are inadvertently printing whitespace in the servlet.